# change name of pv suse linux 12

Tags: linux, lvm

the output of the pv is showing the name of isci name and not the /dev/sda2 for example. Anyone is telling me why I can hange the name of the pv

lxxxxxx:~ # pvs
PV                                                     VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa80xx4** vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7011574** vgbackup lvm2 a--  500.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx19064** vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx31** vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfdf0** vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdd7c** vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdcc** vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c29xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx67** vgshared lvm2 a--  350.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c29xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbc** vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c29xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4e** vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0

**/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c29xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6a** vgbkplog lvm2 a--  400.00g    0

Thanks and regards

Comment: Who creates those volume groups and logcial volumes? Do you see anything in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` that would point to the reason? By default, the `/dev/disk/by-id/` path is allowed in `filters`. Maybe there's some custom config which would point to the right direction.

Comment: I have this configuration:# cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -v '#'

config {

        checks=1

        abort_on_errors=0

        profile_dir="/etc/lvm/profile"
}

devices {

        dir="/dev"

        external_device_info_source="none"

        scan="/dev"

        obtain_device_list_from_udev=1

        filter=["a|/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36.*|", "a|/dev/mapper/.*|", "r|.*|"]

        cache_dir="/etc/lvm/cache"

        cache_file_prefix=""

Comment: yess you were right... after change the filter it shows the right output

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the filter as tells @eblock:

## cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -v '#' | grep filter

```
filter = [ "r|/dev/.*/by-path/.*|", "r|/dev/fd.*|", "r|/dev/cdrom|", "r|/dev/sr.*|", "r|/dev/disk/by-id/usb.*|", "r|loop|", "a/.*/" ]
```

## pvs

connect() failed on local socket: No such file or directory
Internal cluster locking initialisation failed.
WARNING: Falling back to local file-based locking.
Volume Groups with the clustered attribute will be inaccessible.
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sdb   vgbackup lvm2 a--  500.00g    0
/dev/sdc   vgbkplog lvm2 a--  400.00g    0
/dev/sdd   vgshared lvm2 a--  350.00g    0
/dev/sde   vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0
/dev/sdf   vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0
/dev/sdg   vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0
/dev/sdh   vglog    lvm2 a--  128.00g    0
/dev/sdi   vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0
/dev/sdj   vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0
/dev/sdk   vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0
/dev/sdl   vgdata   lvm2 a--  262.00g    0